# keeping the tabs throughout an android app

Tags: android, tabs

In my app I have 4 tabs, in one of the tabs I have a list (tab3).  When 1 of the list options are selected it goes to another activity but then the tabs I have go away.  Is there a way to have them permanently there even when I switch to another activity?

I had the idea of putting the tabs in every XML & Java Class but that just seems redundant and I would think it would show the tabs shifting throughout different activities which I do not want, I would want them to be stationary throughout the whole app.

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TabHost th;
TabSpec specs;
ListView libraryView;
String libraryList[] = {"Item1", "Item2"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Always do this at the start.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_white_text, R.id.library_list_content, libraryList);
    libraryView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    libraryView.setAdapter(adapter);

    libraryView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String librarySelected = libraryList[position];
            Class libraryClass;
            try {           
                libraryClass = Class.forName("com.jj.test.library." + librarySelected);
                Intent libraryIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, libraryClass);
                startActivity(libraryIntent);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });


    //Creating the TabHost and gathering its ID for usage.
    th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);        
    th.setup();

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    specs.setIndicator("tab1");
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    specs.setIndicator("tab2");
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    specs.setIndicator("tab3");
    th.addTab(specs); 

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag4");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab4);
    specs.setIndicator("tab4");
    th.addTab(specs);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </ListView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp" >
        </TabWidget>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And when they click Item1 or Item2 (which is in the list on tab3 and takes them to a different Activity) it doesn't take the tabs with it.  Is there something I need to do to the MainActivity XML or Class to make this persistent throughout the whole app?

Comment: Why dont you create fragments and when on-click of a list item just replace the fragment below the tabs . there wont be any need to create a new activity and you can replace the Fragment using FragmentTransactionManager as well

Comment: If I was to use fragments could they be used on devices pre API 11?

Comment: Yes.You can use the android-v4 compatability package

Comment: So if I used that package would that would allow me to have it work for all APIs, not just pre API 11?